# Что используется вместо CSS и HTML в нативных приложениях

Tags: html, css, веб-дизайн, дизайн

Это из серии 10 глупых вопросов.
Мы используем HTML+CSS для разметки интерфейсов на веб-сайтах, так? Но что используется для создания десктопных приложений вместо этой пары? Например на C++? Там что-то включено уже в сам язык или как? Почему HTML и CSS отделены от JS? 
А что в 3D приложениях?

Comment: хе хе. где как, иногда прям все руками, иногда есть какой то фреймворк. зависит от того что рисовать

Comment: для окошек в с++ популярен qt, в 3д приложухах обычно сам себе создаешь гуи фреймворк

Comment: Конечно, в меня сейчас помидоры полетят, но тем не менее. И для десктопа можно юзать хтмл, цсс и жс. Фреймворк называется Electron JS. На нём, например, написан VSCode тот же. Или Postman. Но если надо плюсы, то да, qt. На джаве либо Swing, либо JavaFX.